# Composite pattern of sealed class that has no interface

Tags: c#, composite, sealed

Let's say that I am using a library that I have *no control* over whatsoever. This library exposes service that requires argument of certain class. Class is *marked as sealed* and has *no interface*.

tl;dr: How can I reimplement **sealed class** as **interface**?

Code example:

```
using System;

namespace IDontHaveControlOverThis
{
    // Note no interface and the class is being sealed
    public sealed class ArgumentClass
    {
        public String AnyCall() => "ArgumentClass::AnyCall";
    }

    public sealed class ServiceClass
    {
        public String ServiceCall(ArgumentClass argument) => $"ServiceClass::ServiceCall({argument.AnyCall()})";
    }
}

namespace MyCode
{
    // Composite pattern, basically I need: "is a ArgumentClass"
    // Obviously doesn't work - can't extend from sealed class
    public class MyArgumentClass : IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass
    {
        private IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass arg = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass();

        public String AnyCall() => $"MyArgumentCLass::AnyCall({arg.AnyCall()})";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // I don't have control over this
        IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass service = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass();


        //This obviously works
        IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass arg = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass();
        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {service.ServiceCall(arg)}");

        // How to make this work?
        IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass myArg = new MyCode.MyArgumentClass();
        Console.WriteLine($"Result: {service.ServiceCall(myArg)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the actual implementation of `ArgumentClass`? That would mean that you can only do the servicecall with the same argument?

Comment: Hey Jesse, thanks for the time. I believe that I have already done that - as you can see the signature itself is identical; but I know of no means to actually mark my class as "is a IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass". I've tried to search for any relevant examples for my case yet I've found none.

Comment: Give a better more accurate example of the actual argument class and what you want to do. Your simplified example will only mislead those formulating a solution to your problem.

Comment: @JessedeWit Yes, I've re-created the case I'm working with. Library specifically sealed argument class, argument class has no interface, and service class requires argument of this particular class.

Comment: But argumentclass will always return the same value? Or do you have possibilities to change the behavior of argumentclass by setting a property, or creating a new instance with different constructor parameters? If you cannot modify the behavior of argumentclass in any way, the answer is _no_.

Comment: If type checking is done at compile time you could inject IL code.

Comment: @JacekLipiec any feedback on the provided solutions?

Comment: @Nikosi Sorry, life happened;/ Picked answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code sample you show, the answer is *you can't*. You need to be able to modify the behavior of `IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass`, by setting a property, or creating a new instance with different constructor parameters in order to modify the servicecall. (It now always returns the same string, so the servicecall is always the same)

If you are able to modify the behavior of the ArgumentClass by setting properties.
You could create wrappers for the sealed classes in your own code, and use that throughout your codebase.

```
public class MyArgumentClass
{
        // TODO: Set this to a useful value of ArgumentClass.
    internal IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass InnerArgumentClass { get; }
    public virtual string AnyCall() => "???";
}

public class MyServiceClass
{
    private IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass innerServiceClass
            = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass();

    public virtual string ServiceCall(MyArgumentClass argument)
    {
        return innerServiceClass.ServiceCall(argument.InnerArgumentClass);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyArgumentClass
{
    public virtual string AnyCall() => "???";
}

public class MyServiceClass
{
    private IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass innerServiceClass
            = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass();

    public string ServiceCall(MyArgumentClass argument)
    {
        var serviceArgument = Convert(argument);
        return innerServiceClass.ServiceCall(serviceArgument);
    }

    private IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass Convert(MyArgumentClass argument)
    {
        // TODO: implement.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error message

> **Cannot implicitly convert** type 'MyCode.MyArgumentClass' to 'IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass'

***note: emphasis mine***

should give you a hint as to what you can do

```
public class MyArgumentClass {
    private IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass arg = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass();

    public String AnyCall() => $"MyArgumentCLass::AnyCall({arg.AnyCall()})";


    public static implicit operator IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass(MyArgumentClass source) {

        return source.arg;
    }
}
```

So now your "wrapper" exposes the 3rd party dependency as needed

```
 IDontHaveControlOverThis.ArgumentClass myArg = new MyCode.MyArgumentClass();
```

or directly

```
var myArg = new MyCode.MyArgumentClass();
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {service.ServiceCall(myArg)}");
```

Reference [User-defined conversion operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Which can allow for abstracting your code

```
namespace MyCode {

    public interface IMyService {
        String ServiceCall(MyArgumentClass argument);
    }

    public class MyServiceClass : IMyService {
        public string ServiceCall(MyArgumentClass argument) {
            IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass service = new IDontHaveControlOverThis.ServiceClass();
            return service.ServiceCall(argument);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the result from this? Based on what the OP wants, I'd assume it should be `ServiceClass::ServiceCall(MyArgumentCLass::AnyCall(ArgumentClass::AnyCall))`. But wouldn't this solution return `ServiceClass::ServiceCall(ArgumentClass::AnyCall)` since the `MyArgumentClass.AnyCall()` is essentially getting bypassed?

Comment: @devNull that is correct, I figured this to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Note my previous comment asking for a better example since this one is misleading